# Prediction using saved model object

Tags: r, predict

I am trying to use predict function in R using a model saved earlier. The model was created and saved using the following code:

```
    lrModel1 <- glm(response ~ .,data = modelData,family = binomial,model = TRUE)
    save(lrModel1,file = "lrModel100.rda")
```

When I load the model for later use as follows and try to use the predict function on it as follows:

```
    bar <- load("lrModel100.rda")
    predicted <- predict(bar,validationData,type = "response")
```

I get the following error:

```
    Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
            no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Is there a way to get the model object name from the saved RDA file and use it for prediction?

Thank you.

Ravi

Comment: it's because your model is still named lrModel1 and not bar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @droopy told you the model's name doesn't change if you save and load. You can use `get` to use the model:

```
predicted <- predict(get(bar),validationData,type = "response")
```

Comment: I have same problem with readRDS(), and get(model) is not working. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you have saved the model earlier it may throw this error.
Reload the library(glmnet) and make sure that number of variables in X & Y are same.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem before.

I used caret to build model, and save the model as a rds file.(saveRDS)

When I readRDS my file, and use this model to predict, I encountered this problem.

After I use "library(caret)", my problem is solved.

So I think if you save your model, and re-open your model to predict, you have to reload the package you used for building model.