# What is causing R error "no applicable method" when using predict on saved data and model (.RData)?

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I have an issue, but
haven't found solutions that work for me.

When calling prediction on a saved object, I get the following error:
Error in UseMethod("predict") :
no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "character"

Note that after loading the saved objects, they show **Values** in my environment. But, when they are first created, they show up as **Data**. Perhaps this is a save/load issue, but I don't see it.

I have the following:

1. Reloaded libraries. No change ([Prediction using saved model object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346633/prediction-using-saved-model-object))
2. Tried solution to #94 (https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/94), and gotten another error (maybe that's about Prophet and not R?):
   Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘devtools’

```
## Load required packages
required.packages = c("ggplot2", "readr", "tidyr", "tree")
lapply (required.packages, require, character.only=TRUE)

## Load data 
data.all <- read.csv("BreastCancerWisconsinDataSet.csv")

## Some simple cleaning and set up
 
# set the target: we are trying to predict whether a diagnosis is malignant (M) or benign (B).
data.all$target [data.all$diagnosis == "M"] = 1
data.all$target [data.all$diagnosis == "B"] = 0

# all variables available for training
vars <- names(data.all)[c(-1, -2, -33)]
data.all <- data.all[c(-1, -2, -33)]

# split data into training vs testing
set.seed(1000)
data.all$rand <- runif(nrow(data.all))
data.training <- data.all[which(data.all$rand <= 0.5), ] 
data.testing <- data.all[which(data.all$rand > 0.5), ]

##
# Save the data.all, data.training and data.testing objects into appropriately named .RData files
##
save(data.all, file = "Chunk_13_35_data_all.RData")
save(data.training, file = "Chunk_13_35_data_training.RData")
save(data.testing, file = "Chunk_13_35_data_testing.RData")


## Clean up (dont need data.all anymore)
rm(data.all)

## Fit a simple decision tree model
Tree.m1 <- tree (target ~ radius_mean + 
                           texture_mean +
                           perimeter_mean +
                           area_mean +
                           smoothness_mean  + 
                           compactness_mean +
                           concavity_mean   +
                           concave.points_mean +
                           symmetry_mean, 
                 data = data.training)

##
# Save the Tree.m1 model into and appropriately named .RData file
##
save(Tree.m1, file = "Chunk_13_35_tree_m1.RData")

## Predict results - re-run this code after you reload the objects you saved. Make sure the results are the same!
Tree.m1.pred.train = predict(Tree.m1, data.training, type = "vector")
Tree.m1.pred.train  = ifelse(Tree.m1.pred.train > 0.5, 1, 0)
error = mean(Tree.m1.pred.train != data.training$target)
print(paste('Tree Training Model Accuracy', 1-error))

Tree.m1.pred.test = predict(Tree.m1, data.testing, type = "vector")
Tree.m1.pred.test = ifelse(Tree.m1.pred.test > 0.5, 1, 0)
error = mean(Tree.m1.pred.test != data.testing$target)
print(paste('Tree Testing Model Accuracy', 1-error))

## Clean up
rm(list = ls()) # This will remove all objects in the environment

######
# Check that can run on saved objects
######

required.packages = c("ggplot2", "readr", "tidyr", "tree")
lapply (required.packages, require, character.only=TRUE)

# Note that tried to add devtools line here.

data.training <- load("Chunk_13_35_data_training.RData")
data.testing <- load("Chunk_13_35_data_testing.RData")
Tree.m1 <- load("Chunk_13_35_tree_m1.RData")

Tree.m1.pred.train = predict(Tree.m1, data.training, type = "vector")   # Error occurs here
Tree.m1.pred.train  = ifelse(Tree.m1.pred.train > 0.5, 1, 0)
error = mean(Tree.m1.pred.train != data.training$target)
print(paste('Tree Training Model Accuracy', 1-error))

Tree.m1.pred.test = predict(Tree.m1, data.testing, type = "vector")
Tree.m1.pred.test = ifelse(Tree.m1.pred.test > 0.5, 1, 0)
error = mean(Tree.m1.pred.test != data.testing$target)
print(paste('Tree Testing Model Accuracy', 1-error))
```

Comment: See if you can distill the issue you're seeing into a very short, clear, reproducible example.  This is a lot of code, which makes hunting for the key problem noisier.  For example, you probably don't need to include all of the specific predictors, or even a proper train/test split, to reproduce the main error with `predict` on a saved object.  At minimum, please provide data that can reproduce the issue (this code loads from a CSV).  But you're much more likely to get better help, faster, with a [mcve].

Comment: BTW, your use of `require` is wrong and prone to unrecognized failure. Either use `library` or do something with what `require` returns. If not, you will at some point silently fail and wonder why package xyz does not seem to be available. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/3358272

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load the object that is written by "save" command, then when you want to load it, you shouldn't have to assign it. Please check the following code :

```
required.packages = c("ggplot2", "readr", "tidyr", "tree")
lapply (required.packages, require, character.only=TRUE)

## Load data 
data.all <- read.csv("BreastCancerWisconsinDataSet.csv")

## Some simple cleaning and set up

# set the target: we are trying to predict whether a diagnosis is malignant (M) or benign (B).
data.all$target [data.all$diagnosis == "M"] = 1
data.all$target [data.all$diagnosis == "B"] = 0

# all variables available for training
vars <- names(data.all)[c(-1, -2, -33)]
data.all <- data.all[c(-1, -2, -33)]

# split data into training vs testing
set.seed(1000)
data.all$rand <- runif(nrow(data.all))
data.training <- data.all[which(data.all$rand <= 0.5), ] 
data.testing <- data.all[which(data.all$rand > 0.5), ]

##
# Save the data.all, data.training and data.testing objects into appropriately named .RData files
##
save(data.all, file = "Chunk_13_35_data_all.RData")
save(data.training, file = "Chunk_13_35_data_training.RData")
save(data.testing, file = "Chunk_13_35_data_testing.RData")


## Clean up (dont need data.all anymore)
rm(data.all)

## Fit a simple decision tree model
Tree.m1 <- tree (target ~ radius_mean + 
                   texture_mean +
                   perimeter_mean +
                   area_mean +
                   smoothness_mean  + 
                   compactness_mean +
                   concavity_mean   +
                   concave.points_mean +
                   symmetry_mean, 
                 data = data.training)

##
# Save the Tree.m1 model into and appropriately named .RData file
##
save(Tree.m1, file = "Chunk_13_35_tree_m1.RData")

## Predict results - re-run this code after you reload the objects you saved. Make sure the results are the same!
Tree.m1.pred.train = predict(Tree.m1, data.training, type = "vector")
Tree.m1.pred.train  = ifelse(Tree.m1.pred.train > 0.5, 1, 0)
error = mean(Tree.m1.pred.train != data.training$target)
print(paste('Tree Training Model Accuracy', 1-error))

Tree.m1.pred.test = predict(Tree.m1, data.testing, type = "vector")
Tree.m1.pred.test = ifelse(Tree.m1.pred.test > 0.5, 1, 0)
error = mean(Tree.m1.pred.test != data.testing$target)
print(paste('Tree Testing Model Accuracy', 1-error))

## Clean up
rm(list = ls()) # This will remove all objects in the environment

######
# Check that can run on saved objects
######

required.packages = c("ggplot2", "readr", "tidyr", "tree")
lapply (required.packages, require, character.only=TRUE)

# Note that tried to add devtools line here.

load("Chunk_13_35_data_training.RData")
load("Chunk_13_35_data_testing.RData")
load("Chunk_13_35_tree_m1.RData")

Tree.m1.pred.train = predict(Tree.m1, data.training, type = "vector")   # Error occurs here
Tree.m1.pred.train  = ifelse(Tree.m1.pred.train > 0.5, 1, 0)
error = mean(Tree.m1.pred.train != data.training$target)
print(paste('Tree Training Model Accuracy', 1-error))

Tree.m1.pred.test = predict(Tree.m1, data.testing, type = "vector")
Tree.m1.pred.test = ifelse(Tree.m1.pred.test > 0.5, 1, 0)
error = mean(Tree.m1.pred.test != data.testing$target)
print(paste('Tree Testing Model Accuracy', 1-error))
```

That's work for me actually.

Furthermore, if you want to save the object then load it with the assigned variable, try using command "saveRDS" then "readRDS"  instead.